# Редирект на именованный маршрут (named route) в web.php (Laravel 5.5+)

Tags: laravel5

Можно ли пользоваться Laravel хелпером `route()` в web.php? Я хочу редирект на именованный маршрут:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::redirect('/me', route('home'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что во время "компиляции" файла web.php, имена маршрутов регистрируются в последнюю очередь. Поэтому таким образом эту задачу выполнить нельзя.

Чтобы достичь желаемого эффекта, можно написать по-старинке:

```
Route::get('me', function () {
  return redirect('home');
}
```

Разница в том, что во втором случае функция будет вызвана после регистрации имён для всех маршрутов, и такой проблемы возникать не будет